# magento 2 plugin settingpageSize

Tags: magento2, plugin, page, elasticsearch

I have created plugin for elasticSearch to set the size of the page

```
<?php

namespace Devall\ElasticsearchPlugin\Plugin\Checkout\Controller;

class EmptyProducts
{
 public function afterResolve($subject, $result)
 {

     $result->setPageSize(30);
     return $result;
 }
}
```

code Looks something like this.
the problem is that when I use pagination and go to the next page there are no products until I reload that page.
Any suggestions ? how Can I fix this?

Comment: Value for **Products per Page on Grid Allowed Value** and **Products per Page on Grid Default Value** should have `$result->setPageSize(30);`(in your case).
Otherwise, you can manage dynamically in the above plugin(`EmptyProducts`) it's self.